# How do I set Image src using url in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble importing img from my folder.

My code looks something like this

Champion

```
class Champion extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "championDiv">
                <div>
                    <img src= {'../pic' + this.props.picSource} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Champion;
```

Index.js

```
//component
import Champion from './Champion/Champion';

//json
import ChampionData from '../champion.json';

class Index extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "championsDiv">
                <Champion
                    picSource = {ChampionData.data.bob.imageurl}/> //string bob.png
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```

And for some reason it shows the null image icon.

It is weird since I am able to import my picture by:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Bob from '../pic/bob.png';

class Champion extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "championDiv">
                <div>
                    <img src= {Bob} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Champion;
```

However, I dont want to import all 250 images individually.

Any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Comment: If you are using webpack you need to do `<img src={require('../pic/bob.png')} />`

Answer (score 0):

In your `index` component, you need to use `require` to include your images source.

```
//component
import Champion from './Champion/Champion';

//json
import ChampionData from '../champion.json';

class Index extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "championsDiv">
                <Champion
                    picSource = {require(ChampionData.data.bob.imageurl)}/> //string bob.png
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Or you must `import` your images first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import React from "react";
 import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

 function App() {
   return (
     <img 
      src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"
      alt="new"
      />
   );
 }

 const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way...**

```js
//component
import Champion from './Champion/Champion';

//json
import ChampionData from '../champion.json';

var images = require.context('../images/yourImageFolder', true);

class Index extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                    <img src= {images(`./imageName.png`)} />
             </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```